# which of given function is monotone in interval $[0, 1]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Which one of the following is monotonic in $[0,1]$

1. $\sin\frac x{10}e^{\sin\frac x{10}}$
2. $\cos \frac x{10}$
3. $\sin e^{10x}$
4. $\cos e^{10x}$

please explain How to solve this  questions? ...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

For a differentiable function $f$, what does the sign of $f'(x)$ tell you?

Comment: @ 5xum.. still not getting...

Comment: @Prasanta But you are aware that there exists such a thing as a derivative of a function and you are aware that it is somehow connected to the fact that the function is increasing or decreasing?

Answer (score 1):

HINT (without differential calculus, if you know basic properties of functions in the question): $x/10\leq1/10$ hence in a), b) $\sin$ is increasing and $\cos$ is decreasing (and $\exp$ is always nonnegative and increasing). $10x\in[0,10]$ hence in c) and d) you have at least a few periods.

Comment: @ Przemysław Scherwentke ...what is answer of question...

Comment: @Prasanta From the hint it is easy to show that a) is increasing and b) decreasing. One means here two. :-)

Comment: @Prasanta You do realize that you can solve the question yourself using the hints? It will help you much more than just copying answers from other users...